# Change iCloud Backup from new version of iOS to older version

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, backup

I have iPhone 5s with iOS 11.1.
Few weeks ago had to change back my iOS version from a new version because my iPhone did not work well with the new one.

Since then I can not backup to iCloud. When I try it says:

> The last backup could not be completed because it was iCloud backed up by a newer version of iOS.

How can I change iCloud to get my older version back?

Comment: It would be beneficial to include the precise wording of the error message so others can find it

Comment: The precise wording was in Hebrew, so i wrote the translation i made

Answer (score 5):

Go to Settings → *your Apple ID* → iCloud → Manage Storage → Backup and delete the existing backup. Choose to delete and disable backups. Once the backup is removed, try to back up again from scratch.